# Is it possible to turn a string into an object reference?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to make something a little more generic in an Access 2K7 database.  I've got a form that I'm passing some info to using OpenArgs.  I'm passing a form name, subform name and field name, so the field can be populated.

I'm running into trouble "rebuilding" the reference to the field.  I've tried the following, but VBA doesn't like it:

```
Dim strForm, strField, strSubForm As String
Dim frm As Form

strForm = Left(Me.OpenArgs, InStr(Me.OpenArgs, "|") - 1)
Brk1 = Mid(Me.OpenArgs, InStr(Me.OpenArgs, "|") + 1)
strField = Left(Brk1, InStr(Brk1, "|") - 1)
strSubForm = Mid(Brk1, InStr(Brk1, "|") + 1)

X = "Forms!" & strForm
Y = X & "!" & strSubForm
Z = Y & "!" & strField
frm(Z) = Me.Calendar0.Value
```

The object of this exercize is to pass the value of the calendar (Me.Calendar0.Value) to the field on the subform (Forms!strForm!strSubForm!strField).  I just can't figure out how to write that in a way that VBA will accept it.  I'm getting an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tinkering around in the VBA editor leads me to suspect that something like this might work:

```
Dim sbf As SubForm
Set frm = Forms(strForm)
Set sbf = frm.Controls(strSubForm)
sbf.Controls(strField).Value = me.Calendar0.Value
Set sbf = Nothing
Set frm = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

You have ...

```
Dim frm As Form
```

... but later you try to use `frm` without first setting it to a form instance.  That's why you get the error about the object variable not set.

But there is another issue which may be waiting to bite you.  A form can contain a subform control and the name of that control may not be the same as the name of the form it contains.  Make sure you're using the name of the subform *control*.

If `strSubForm` is the subform control, this should work ...

```
Forms(strForm).Controls(strSubForm).Form.Controls(strField) = Me.Calendar0.Value
```